# Is ivy (genus Hedera) a shrub or an herb?

Tags: botany, classification

It seems like the [difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrub) between a bush (shurb) and an herb is that a bush has a woody stem.

What does that make ivy (genus Hedera)? I know that ivy can get a pretty hard stem, does that count as woody? Is there something between a bush and an herb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woody plants are usually either trees, shrubs, or lianas. Ivies are lianas, they can have 40 years of woody growth rings and bark. The categories are flexible. It's an arbitrary division for convenience, it isn't that clear cut. Bamboos for example, are a woody grass.

https://weedwise.conservationdistrict.org/weeds/english-ivy#foobox-1/7/Untitled-4-copy.jpg

Does that count as a woody plant? yes it's a woody liana.

Comment: Wow, that is one impressive ivy stem. - Thanks for the info, it does seem like liana would be the category to place ivy in.

Comment: Cheers, villager. It's happened often that I chop through an ivy and that it takes a few minutes with a saw and I think "I can't believe how tough these darned ivies are!!!" they are so tough. it's so woody it's surprising, you'd think it was another vascular flesh than a tree... ivy is like a real tree inside.